# How to unfold UV texture

Tags: uv

I merged two different meshs to make the object in this picture.
And I attempted to  visualize whole UV texture of this mesh  but only came out that a picture of tongue which have been  assigned to one side of mesh that I used to merge showed up.
As a part of top of her head to middle of it,I used this mesh.
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/spiderman-original-2ed06987d6204854a7fe133684cb66e3

but as other part of head,I used this mesh.
https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/woman/woman-brown-skirt

And as body part, I used this mesh.

How should I do if want to visualize UV texture of whole this object?
And how to apply textures that I downloaded to this object?[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "unfold UV texture"? Do you mean that you check the different textures that have been assigned to your object? Is it the only one that you can visualize? Maybe share your file?

Comment: Hello, PO EX, please be a bit more specific. Give us an idea of which meshes you merged.. and.. did they have their own UV maps? Did one map overwrite the other when you made the merge?

Comment: I think you have to learn the basics of UV mapping and materials before asking broad questions like this one. If you need to assign a particular texture to the tongue, you can do so by selecting the tongue in edit mode, going into material properties, creating a new material and clicking assign.